# When I try to connect two tables django raises an error "type object 'StudyRecord' has no attribute 'object'"

Tags: django

when I try :

```
StudyRecord.object.filter(user__name__contains= id )
```

the django cast the following error :

> AttributeError at /tag_study/my_infor/
>   type object 'StudyRecord' has no attribute 'object'

Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

```
    C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.7.3py2.7.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py in get_responseresponse = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
   ▶ Local vars
   c:\mystudio\tag_study\views.py in my_inforurrent_book = StudyRecord.object.filter(user__name__contains= id ) ...
   ▶ Local vars
```

the StudyRecord models:

```
    class StudyRecord(models.Model):
             user = models.ForeignKey(User)
             book = models.CharField(max_length=128)
             starttime= models.DateTimeField()
             endtime = models.DateTimeField()
        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
             self.slug = slugify(self.number)
             super(StudyRecord, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        def __unicode__(self):      #For Python 2, use __str__ on Python 3
             return self.book
```

and this is the views

```
    def my_infor(request):
        if request.method == "GET":
            if request.user.is_authenticated():
               id = request.user.id
                StudyRecord.object.filter(user__name__contains= id )
                return HttpResponse(current_book)
        else:
            return HttpResponse("error2")
        context = RequestContext(request)
        return render_to_response('tag_study/my_infor.html', context)
```

Comment: You have a typo, it's `objects`, not `object`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be objects, not object

Answer (score 0):

When you get data from db, you need a `Manager` through which you can construct the `QuerySet` you wanted.

> Each model has at least one Manager, and it’s called objects by default.

More info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-objects).